# Can Pageant be used by Windows services?

Tags: ssh, windows-service, putty

Is it possible to configure Pageant (SSH key management) so that its keys are usable by a Windows service with the "Log On As" user of "Local System"?

If not, is there any other tool that can do this?

EDIT:

I've tried setting Pageant up as a service (using runassvc.exe), passing the appropriate key, and having it run as "Local System".  The other service doesn't seem to be able to see the key from the pageant service.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Going with OpenSSH might be easier in an headless environment (if you can switch from `plink` to plain old `ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start Pageant as a service, I assume that your keyfiles do not contain a password. In that case, why not use the keyfiles directly by the second service?

The reason for using Pageant is to keep the keyfile passwords cached.